# how to send push notification without apple device

Tags: notifications, push

is it possible to send push notification for apple without apple device? I would like to send push notification using any page or service from apple, but not using an app created in xcode for example. My app that will get the push is ready and working, but I would like to send the push from a normal page, not from mac or iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple push notifications can only be send to Apple devices (iOS, OSX or Safari for Mac).
However, you can send the notification from any type of operating system using the Apple Push Notification Service API:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/remotenotificationspg/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that for free with using a push notification API, such as Spontit.

See the API docs here: https://api.spontit.com/

See the Python wrapper here: https://github.com/spontit/spontit-api-python-wrapper